# Java Asteroids game how to be able to fire multiple shots without having the first shot disappear?

Tags: java, arrays, game-physics

So for my final in Java class, we are making an Asteroid game (except a simpler version that the official one, because not enough time).

The problem is when our ship fires a shot (SPACE bar) we add(shot, x, y), but then when we click SPACE bar again it just takes that shot and puts it back to original x, y. So right now we can only fire off one shot at a time to be on the screen. We would like to be able to be able to fire off multiple shots and have them all be visible and stuff.

Not sure how to do that though. Any help is welcome thank you.

P.S. if needed i will add our code.
P.S.S. sorry for posting this again i thought i could edit the post later, thats why i didn't include the code but apparently not.

```
package week7Homework;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;

public class space8bit extends GraphicsProgram
{
    /* Initialize everything that is needed */
      final int WIN_HEIGHT = 800;
      final int WIN_WIDTH = 1900;
      GImage space = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/outerspace.png");
      GImage ship = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/ship.png");
      GImage explosion = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/explosion.png");
      GImage [] ast = new GImage[6];
      Random rand = new Random();
      pewpew shots = new pewpew();
      int shipx;
      int shipy;



public void init()
{
      setSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
      add(space);
      ship.setLocation(50,330);
      ship.scale(.8);
      add(ship);
      addKeyListeners( );

      //scale explosion
      explosion.scale(.5);

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
int key = e.getKeyCode( );
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
{ ship.move(0, -15); }
/*else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
{ xMove = MV_AMT; }*/
else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
{ ship.move(0, 15); }
else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
{shipx =  (int)ship.getX()+195;
shipy = (int)ship.getY() + 80;
    add(shots,shipx,shipy);
}

}
public void asteriods()
{
    GImage ast1 = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/asteriod.png",1300,100);
    GImage ast2 = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/asteriod.png",1750,250);
    GImage ast3 = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/asteriod.png",1650,350);
    GImage ast4 = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/asteriod.png",1550,650);
    GImage ast5 = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/asteriod.png",1450,600);
    GImage ast6 = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/asteriod.png",1350,750);
    ast [0] =  ast1;
    ast [1] =  ast2;
    ast [2] =  ast3;
    ast [3] =  ast4;
    ast [4] =  ast5;
    ast [5] =  ast6;

    add(ast[0]);
    add(ast[1]);
    add(ast[2]);
    add(ast[3]);
    add(ast[4]);
    add(ast[5]);


}

public void run()
{
    asteriods();
    while(true)
    {
        pause(120);

        int random1x = rand.nextInt(-1+1+6)-9;
        int random2x = rand.nextInt(-1+1+6)-15;
        int random3x = rand.nextInt(-1+1+6)-25;
        int random4x = rand.nextInt(-1+1+6)-16;
        int random5x = rand.nextInt(-1+1+6)-8;
        int random6x = rand.nextInt(-1+1+6)-13;

        ast[0].move(random1x, 0);
        ast[1].move(random2x, 0);
        ast[2].move(random3x, 0);
        ast[3].move(random4x, 0);
        ast[4].move(random5x, 0);
        ast[5].move(random6x, 0);

        shots.move(50, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < ast.length; i++)
        {
            //integer that gets bounds of all rectangles and ovals in the arrays. 
            GRectangle asteroidBounds = ast[i].getBounds();

            //check for collision with other objects
            if (shots.getBounds().intersects(asteroidBounds))
            {
                int shotX = (int)shots.getX();
                int shotY = (int)shots.getY();

                pause(10);
                remove(ast[i]);
                add(explosion, shotX-100, shotY - 50);
                remove(shots);
                pause(25);
                remove(explosion);


            }

            else if (ship.getY() <= 0)
            {
                ship.move(0, 15);
            }
            else if (ship.getY() >= WIN_HEIGHT - 168)
            {
                ship.move(0, -15);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

ALSO HERE IS A SAMPLE CODE, much shorter but does the same thing. Just press SPACEBAR and you will see what im talking about.

```
package week7Homework;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class collisionTry extends GraphicsProgram 
{

    final int WIN_WIDTH = 500;
    final int WIN_HEIGHT = 500;


    GOval ship = new GOval(100, 250, 50, 50);

    GImage bullet = new GImage("/College/IT219/Week7/src/week7Homework/bullet.gif", 50, 50);

    GImage bullet2;


    boolean bulletFired;


    public void init()
    {
        setSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);

        addKeyListeners();

    }



    public void run()
    {
        GRect rect = new GRect(400, 200, 50, 150);


        add(rect);
        rect.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        rect.setFilled(true);

        add(ship);
        ship.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        ship.setFilled(true);

        while (true)
        {
            pause(50);
            rect.move(-1, 0);

            //bullet.move(5, 0);

            if (bulletFired == true)
            {
                bullet.move(5, 0);

            }

            if (bullet.getBounds().intersects(rect.getBounds()))
            {
                remove(rect);
                remove(bullet);
            }
        }

    }//run

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {

            int shipX = (int)ship.getX();
            int shipY = (int)ship.getY();
            add(bullet, shipX+50, shipY+25);
            bulletFired = true;

        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            ship.move(0, -5);
        }
    }





}
```

Comment: Here is a sample code, if you press space a couple times you will see exactly what i mean.

Comment: [Don't post duplicates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625436/java-asteroids-game-how-to-be-able-to-fire-multiple-shots-without-having-the-fi) If you have information to add, edit your original post.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see it right away, and i googled it, but it said that it's a privilege to edit posts (i thought it applies to your own posts too) sorry. And now im blocked haha, even thought i have more questions. fml.

Answer (score 1):

It's 'cause you only have 1 bullet in the entire game

```
if (bulletFired == true) {
    bullet.move(5, 0);
}
```

You're telling that one bullet to go back to (5, 0)

You need to find some way of making a new bullet object each time you press space:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    int shipX = (int)ship.getX();
    int shipY = (int)ship.getY();

    Bullet firedBullet = new Bullet(/* params if any, x? y? */);

    add(firedBullet, shipX+50, shipY+25);
    bulletFired = true;
}
```

Though this is my vision of how I'd do things, which probably won't work with your game (I don't know what classes you have, their roles etc). But hopefully you can see what I'm getting at and adapt it.

Now because you have multiple bullets, you also have to take care of their lifetimes. You fired 1000 bullets at the start of the game, they go off-screen. You don't want to waste time drawing them for the rest of the game. So whatever list/array you're using to keep track of objects to draw, you gotta periodically find and remove the ones that have gone off-screen.